# Continuously run function while on mouseenter- Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, mouseevent

How do I get the function to loop/continue as long as I'm on mouseenter? If I add colorPixels() after the duration in the first script, it doesn't stop on mouseleave.

```
                  <script type="text/javascript">
              function pixelColors(){
              var color = 'rgb('+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+')';
              $('#logo_back').animate({
                           backgroundColor:color
                        }, 2000);

              }
              </script>


              <script>

              $(document).ready(function() {

              $("#logo").bind('mouseenter', function() {
              pixelColors() } );


              $("#logo").bind('mouseleave', function() {
              jQuery(this).stop(true, true);


              });

              });



              </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var mouseOver = false;
function pixelColors() {
    if (mouseOver) {
    var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ')';
    $('#logo_back').animate({
        backgroundColor: color
    }, 2000, pixelColors);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#logo").bind('mouseenter', function() {
        mouseOver = true;
        pixelColors();
    });


    $("#logo").bind('mouseleave', function() {
        mouseOver = false;
    });

});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jfebC/

Or, using `.stop()` like you are doing currently:

```
function pixelColors() {
    var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ')';
    $('#logo_back').animate({
        backgroundColor: color
    }, 2000, pixelColors);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#logo").bind('mouseenter', pixelColors);

    $("#logo").bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $("#logo_back").stop();
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TyybP/

Comment: This doesn't do what OP wanted. OP wanted to stop when you mouseover

Comment: From the original post *"How do I get the function to loop/continue as long as I'm on mouseenter?"*

Comment: Hey Andrew! Door #2 is perfect- thank you! I love how something as simple as a '(' can throw your whole game...I was so close! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `pixelColors()` animation restart itself from the completion function and thus it will run indefinitely until you call `.stop()` on `mouseleave`.  And, you just make sure that it stops calling itself when the mouse is no longer hovering.  There are several ways to do that.  I chose to do it here, using a piece of state saved on the actual animation object using jQuery.data().  It could also be done with a global variable or a variable in a higher/shared scope.

```
function pixelColors() {
    var color = 'rgb('+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+')';
    $('#logo_back').animate({
        backgroundColor:color
    }, 2000, function() {
         if ($('#logo_back').data("mouseenter")) {
             pixelColors()  // call it again, if mouse still over
         }
    });
}

$("#logo").bind('mouseenter', function() {
     $('#logo_back').data("mouseenter", true);  // set state of mouse hover
     pixelColors() } );


  $("#logo").bind('mouseleave', function() {
     $('#logo_back').data("mouseenter", false);  // clear state of mouse hover
      jQuery(this).stop(true, true);
  }
```